# case class having primary constructor without having a no parameter in scala

Tags: scala

I was trying to create a case class in scala.

```
     case class CaseClassPrimaryConstructor {  
} //Error: case classes without a parameter list are not allowed; use either case objects or case classes with an explicit `()' as a parameter list.



 case class CaseClassPrimaryConstructor() {

} // Working  fine
```

did not understand the behavior ? please help

Comment: What exactly not clear?? Did you have a chance to read documentation? http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html  If this a syntax related question. I would say accept it as it is ....

Comment: thanks for the link. My doubt is, when we define a normal class then both declaration works fine and having same impact/result but for case class why first one reports the mentioned error but second one works properly where both having same meaning, as per my knowledge. Am I missing something to understand the difference?

Comment: Well. A bit difficult to write proper answer. Case class expecting some parameters in declaration. So in you example you just specify nothing. It just special notation. thats it.

Comment: You can actually avoid writing parenthesis if you don't include the `{  }`.
Just write `case class CaseClassPrimaryConstructor` and that should be enough.
Also the reason the first piece of code doesn't work is so that the compiler can tell apart closures from one argument bracket syntactic sugar

Comment: Thanks. That make sense. Just want to add my observation . I was trying to create an instance like "caseObj:CaseClassPrimaryConstructor=CaseClassPrimaryConstructor" which is not valid saying "type mismatch; found : CaseClassPrimaryConstructor.type required: com.basic.constructor.CaseClassPrimaryConstructor"

Answer (score 2):

It used to be allowed, but isn't anymore precisely for the reason mentioned in your last comment:

> I was trying to create an instance like "caseObj:CaseClassPrimaryConstructor=CaseClassPrimaryConstru‌​ctor" which is not valid saying "type mismatch; found : CaseClassPrimaryConstructor.type required: com.basic.constructor.CaseClassPrimaryConstructor"

`CaseClassPrimaryConstru‌​ctor` in an expression context (not after `:` or in type parameter, or after `new`) means the companion *object* of the `CaseClassPrimaryConstru‌​ctor` class, so you would still get the same error, which was rather confusing. For case classes, this companion object has `apply` method with the same parameters as the primary constructor which just calls it. `CaseClassPrimaryConstru‌​ctor()` isn't really a special syntax for constructing case classes, it's syntax for calling the `apply` method.

Also, instead of a case class without parameters you *generally* want an `object` in the first place, since all instances will be equal, they shouldn't behave differently and so there is no need to create new instances at all.